# When does the infinite recursive fraction integral $\int_a^b \frac{g(x_1)dx_1}{\int_a^{x_1}\frac{g(x_2)dx_2}{\int_a^{x_2}\cdots}}$ converge?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

I write problems for integration bees, and I am considering problems of the form in the title, i.e.

$$\int_a^b \frac{g(x_1)dx_1}{\int_a^{x_1}\frac{g(x_2)dx_2}{\int_a^{x_2}\frac{g(x_3)dx_3}{\int_a^{x_3}\cdots}}}$$

where $g$ is of the special form

$$\begin{cases}g(x) = f(x)f'(x) \\ f(a) = 0 \\ f(x)\geq 0\end{cases}$$

Or more formally, consider the sequence

$$F_{n+1}(x) = \int_a^x \frac{g(t)dt}{F_n(t)} \hspace{20 pt}F_0(t) =  1$$

If $g$ is of the special form above, in the limit we get

$$F'(x) = \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{F(x)} \implies F(x) = |f(x)|$$

by L'Hopital's rule. I think a necessary condition for convergence might be $f'(x) \geq 0$ as taking $f(x) = \sin x$ it looks like the sequence diverges if $b > \frac{\pi}{2}$ when $a=0$, but I am not sure if this is a sufficient condition. This gives a solution

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x_1\cos x_1\:dx_1}{\int_0^{x_1}\frac{\sin x_2 \cos x_2 \:dx_2}{\int_0^{x_3}\frac{\sin x_3 \cos x_3 \:dx_3}{\int_0^{x_3}\cdots}}} = 1$$

$\textbf{My Question}$: Is $f'(x)\geq 0$ is a sufficient (or even necessary) condition for convergence? If not, what other conditions would I need on the kernel $g$ to get limit convergence? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you comment why it looks like it diverges for $b > \pi/2$?

Comment: @user196574 plotting the first couple functions of the sequence on wolfram, they look like quickly grow singularities beyond that point because you get functions of secants and such

Comment: I'm tempted that those may be integrable singularities, like $\int_{-1}^1 -\log(|x|) dx =2$, but I'll check it out in more detail when I get a chance. I'll add that it's typically hard for an integral $\int_a^b dx k(x)$ to diverge when the upper bound is larger than some critical value, $b>b_c$, but converge at the critical value $b=b_c$. It's more common for, if an integral diverges for $b>b_c$, that it also diverges when $b=b_c$.

Comment: This is a nice and interesting/challenging problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the kind words :) If I drop the $f(a)=0$ condition, do you have any numerical thoughts on $g(x)= e^{2x}$ on $[0,b]$? According to the limit it should be $F(x) = \sqrt{e^{2x}-1}$ but I haven't had much success quantifying how close (if at all) the sequence approaches this function with each $n$ step.

Comment: @user196574 There is the possibility that it converges, just not to that specific $f$. It seems like the limit function might always increase so the limit on the extended interval might be something of the form $$F(x) = \sin(\arctan(\tan x)) + 2\left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$ (if you plot this it looks much nicer and more natural than it appears)